# Where to put property file that is used across different modules in a multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, maven, properties, multi-module

i have created a nice multi-module project using maven, but now i am wondering what the best place would be to store property files that shared accross modules. To give an example i have 4 modules all needing a log4j.properties file, do i need to put it in every module or is there a central place in which to put this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parent project, this would be the best place.

Otherwise a module that is included by each other module.

Put the `log4j.properties` into `/src/main/resources`